Filter rows using Row number and partition by columns and a business logic
For suppose lets consider the below set of table



Class
Class
rule
version
RuleAvailable




Class 1
Class1-Csx -02.01
Csx
02.01
Yes


Class1
Class1- Csx -01.01
Csx
01.01
Yes


Class1
Class1-CsxBusrule -02.01
CsxBusrule
02.01
Withdrawn


Class1
Class1-CsxBusrule -01.01
CsxBusrule
01.01
Yes


Class1
Class1 - Csxfw -01.01
Csxfw
01.01
Yes


Class2
Class2 - Csx - 02.01
Csx
02.01
Yes


Class2
Class2 - Csxbusrule -02.01
Csxbusrule
02.01
Yes


Class3
Class3 - Csxfw -02.01
Csxfw
02.01
Not Available


Class3
Class3 - Csxfw -01.01
Csxfw
01.01
Yes



Here, firstly we have to do partition of class and then rule and then by version
This is the order of rulesets
CSXBusrule>> CSX >> CSXFW
If the top version of the rule is withdrawn, we have to ignore that rule and go with the rule in next available order
If the top version of the rule is Not Available, we have to ignore that version and go with the next version in next available order
For each Unique Class, if we have three rules Csx ,CsxBusrule , Csxfw we should take Csxbusrule into consideration and then return the higher version of it. and if the higher version of Csxbusrule is withdrawn, we should not take any rows in csxbusrule, we should ignore csxbusrule and then take csx as per order
If for a class there is only rule Csxfw, higher version of that row should be returned
Below is the expected result



Class
Key
RUle
Version
ruleavailable




Class 1
Class1-Csx-02.01
Csx
02.01
Yes


Class2
Class2 - Csxbusrule -02.01
Csxbusrule
02.01
Yes


Class3
Class3 - Csxfw-01.01
Csxfw
01.01
Yes



Select 
  Key ,
  Class, 
  Rule , 
  Version 
FROM 
(
  SELECT 
    t.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() 
      OVER (PARTITION BY class ORDER BY 
                    CASE rule WHEN 'CSXBusRule' THEN 1 
                              WHEN 'CSX' THEN 2 
                              WHEN 'CSXFW' THEN 3 END, version DESC) AS rn 
  FROM table t 
  where 
    pyRuleAvailable='Yes'
) 

WHERE rn = 1,

tried this, but this doesnt include withdrawn logic, we have to ignore the rule and go with next rule order if the higher version of that rule is withdrawn, how to do it

with X as (select *, row_number() over (partition by class, rule order by version desc) as rnx from T), Y as (select *, row_number() over (partition by class order by case rule when 'CSXBusRule' then 1 when 'CSX' then 2 when 'CSXFW' then 3 end) as rny from X where RuleActive = 'Yes') select * from Y where rny = 1 @shawnt00 where exactly

You've also asked this exact question for SQL server? Do you need an answer for both? Or do you need to delete that question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78941862/ignore-other-rows-based-on-two-column-values-after-partition

@DaleK deleted the same

Could you please take class 3 logic also into consideration where if top verion of rule is not available, we should take the next available version @shawnt00

From Oracle 12, you can set the priority of the rules and then use MATCH_RECOGNIZE for row-by-row pattern matching:
SELECT Key,
       Class, 
       Rule, 
       Version,
       RuleAvailable
FROM   (
         SELECT Key,
                Class, 
                Rule, 
                Version,
                RuleAvailable,
                DECODE(rule, 'CsxBusrule', 1, 'Csx', 2, 'Csxfw', 3) AS rule_priority,
                DECODE(ruleavailable, 'Withdrawn', 1, 'Yes', 2) AS available_priority
         FROM   table_name
       )
       MATCH_RECOGNIZE(
         PARTITION BY key
         ORDER BY rule_priority, available_priority, version DESC
         ALL ROWS PER MATCH
         PATTERN (^ {- ( withdrawn+ same_rule* )* -} not_withdrawn )
         DEFINE
           withdrawn AS RuleAvailable = 'Withdrawn',
           same_rule AS Rule = PREV(rule)
       )

In earlier versions, you can use:
SELECT Key,
       Class, 
       Rule, 
       Version,
       RuleAvailable
FROM   (
  SELECT Key,
         Class, 
         Rule, 
         Version,
         RuleAvailable,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY key
           ORDER BY rule_priority, version DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   (
    SELECT Key,
           Class, 
           Rule, 
           Version,
           RuleAvailable,
           COUNT(CASE RuleAvailable WHEN 'Withdrawn' THEN 1 END) OVER (
             PARTITION BY key, rule
           ) AS num_withdrawn,
           DECODE(rule, 'CsxBusrule', 1, 'Csx', 2, 'Csxfw', 3) AS rule_priority
    FROM   table_name
  )
  WHERE  num_withdrawn = 0
)
WHERE  rn = 1;

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE table_name (Key, rule, version, RuleAvailable) AS
SELECT 'Class1', 'Csx',        '02.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class1', 'Csx',        '01.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class1', 'CsxBusrule', '02.01', 'Withdrawn' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class1', 'CsxBusrule', '01.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class1', 'Csxfw',      '01.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class2', 'Csx',        '02.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class2', 'CsxBusrule', '02.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class3', 'Csxfw',      '01.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL

ALTER TABLE table_name ADD class VARCHAR2(50) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (
  key || '-' || rule || '-' || version
)

Both output:



KEY
CLASS
RULE
VERSION
RULEAVAILABLE




Class1
Class1-Csx-02.01
Csx
02.01
Yes


Class2
Class2-CsxBusrule-02.01
CsxBusrule
02.01
Yes


Class3
Class3-Csxfw-01.01
Csxfw
01.01
Yes



fiddle

with X as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by class, rule order by version desc) as rnx
    from T
), Y as (
    select *, row_number() over (partition by class order by case rule when 'CSXBusRule' then 1 when 'CSX' then 2 when 'CSXFW' then 3 end) as rny 
    from X
    where rnx = 1 and RuleActive = 'Yes'
)
select * from Y where rny = 1;


Could you please take class 3 logic also into consideration where if top verion of rule is not available, we should take the next available version @shawnt00

Ok, those are now eliminated in the first step.

Take first row with order (rule priority, version).
We use joined ord - priority of rule.
Full query
select *
from (
select t.* 
  ,row_number()over(partition by class order by ord,version desc) as rn
from test t
left join rulepriority p on t.rulename=p.rulename
where RuleAvailable='Yes'
)t
where rn=1




CLASS
RULENAME
VERSION
RULEAVAILABLE
RN




Class1
Csx
02.01
Yes
1


Class2
CsxBusrule
02.01
Yes
1


Class3
Csxfw
01.01
Yes
1



For row ordering  use table (subquery)
create table rulepriority (rulename,ord) as
SELECT 'CsxBusrule',1 FROM DUAL union all
SELECT 'Csx'       ,2 FROM DUAL union all
SELECT 'Csxfw'     ,3  FROM DUAL 

Upd1. join condition on ... is case sensitive.



RULENAME
ORD




CsxBusrule
1


Csx
2


Csxfw
3



Calculate row_number( partition by class order by version desc,ord)
for filtered rows (RuleAvailable='Yes').
Output
select t.* 
  ,row_number()over(partition by class order by ord,version desc) as rn
from test t
left join rulepriority p on t.rulename=p.rulename
where RuleAvailable='Yes'





CLASS
RULENAME
VERSION
RULEAVAILABLE
RN




Class1
Csx
02.01
Yes
1


Class1
CsxBusrule
01.01
Yes
2


Class1
Csxfw
01.01
Yes
3


Class1
Csx
01.01
Yes
4


Class2
CsxBusrule
02.01
Yes
1


Class2
Csx
02.01
Yes
2


Class3
Csxfw
01.01
Yes
1



new fiddle.
old fiddle
There we use
CREATE TABLE test (class, rulename, version, RuleAvailable) AS
SELECT 'Class1', 'Csx',        '02.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class1', 'Csx',        '01.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class1', 'CsxBusrule', '02.01', 'Withdrawn' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class1', 'CsxBusrule', '01.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class1', 'Csxfw',      '01.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class2', 'Csx',        '02.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class2', 'CsxBusrule', '02.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Class3', 'Csxfw',      '01.01', 'Yes' FROM DUAL


I think its only coincidence that this returns the expected answer for the OP's data. If you add some extra data fiddle then the Class4 row returned is for the lower-priority Csxfw row, with the higher version number, and not the expected higher-priority Csx row, with the lower version number.

Thank you for testing and comment. I read the question again. Order should be ord, version desc. Updated.(https://dbfiddle.uk/ONPUw4-h)
